# Javascript function to change links every minute

Tags: javascript

I need to create a script that will create a link that will change every minute. My javascript is poor, I wrote some script but it's not working. Can anyone help me please? This is what I got so far:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var arr = [];

arr[0]= new Link();
arr[0].href = "http://www.youtube.com/";
arr[1]= new Link();
arr[1].href = "http://www.forever21.com/";
arr[2]= new Link();
arr[2].href = "http://www.amazon.com/";
arr[3]= new Link();
arr[3].href = "http://www.ebay.com/";
arr[4]= new Link();
arr[4].href = "http://www.zara.com/";
arr[5]= new Link();
arr[5].href = "http://www.southwest.com/";
arr[6]= new Link();
arr[6].href = "http://oldnavy.gap.com/";

function slide(){
 document.getElementById("link1").href= arr[i].href;
 i++;
 if(i==arr.length){
  i=0;
 }
 setTimeout(function(){ slide(); },2000);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="slide('link1',arr);">
<h1>WELCOME</h1>
<div id="link">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/" id="link1"><h1 text align="center">Click to go to <br> www.youtube.com</h1></a></div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You never declare/initialize the `i` variable. Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: `Link` isn't a standar Object in javascript.

Comment: Something like this? http://fiddle.jshell.net/nGVhp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

```
var arr = ["http://www.youtube.com/", "http://www.forever21.com/", "http://www.amazon.com/", "http://www.ebay.com/", "http://www.zara.com/",     "http://www.southwest.com/", "http://oldnavy.gap.com/"];
var i=0;

function slide(){
    document.getElementById("link1").href= arr[i];
    document.getElementById("site").innerText = arr[i];
    i++;
    if(i==arr.length){
        i=0;
    }
}

setInterval(slide, 2000);
```

And HTML code:

```
<h1 align="center">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/" id="link1">Click to go to <br> <span id="site">http//www.youtube.com</span>
</h1>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B8CwT/

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("link1").href= arr[i].href;
```

This function is equivalent to

```
document.getElementById("link1").href= arr[undefined].href;
```

And so i++ is also undefined.

Just initialize with

```
var i = 0;
```